# adding https dynamically to url

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, https, ssl-certificate

I want to set https to my url dynamically. I just want to use https on my login and basket aspx files. Here is my codes:

In html file:

```
   <span runat="server" id="spnGiris"><a href="<%#GetDomain(true)%>/Login.aspx">Personel
                Girişi&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span>
<a href="<%#GetDomain(false)%>/Default.aspx?q=e">Çıkış</a></span>
```

In server side:

```
 public string GetDomain(bool https)
    {
        string protocol = https ? "https" : "http";
        string s = Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
        if (s.Equals("localhost"))
            return protocol + "://localhost:14553";
        return protocol + "://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domainName"];
    }
```

I put breakpoint on GetDomain and https is always false in login.aspx. But In basket.aspx everything is ok.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You code is clearing calling GetDomain(true)  you'll have to provide more information as to why GetDomain(true) isn't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed <%#GetDomain(true)%> with <%=GetDomain(true)%> and it resolved.